# Why netlogo gives me error with set [] of x

Tags: netlogo

i have a question that i cant find answer anywhere , i have my code like this:

```
exemple-own[energy]

ask exemple[
    let me one-of exemple-on patch-ahead 1    
    set [energy] of me [energy] of me + energy
]
```

"This isn't something you can use set on"
am i use set right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only change the value of an agent's attribute from the perspective of that agent and you change perspectives with an `ask`. I think you want this:

```
exemple-own[energy]

ask exemple [
    let me one-of exemple-on patch-ahead 1    
    ask me [ set energy energy + [energy] of myself ]
]
```

The keyword `myself` refers to the asker.